# How to increment SRAM address like 60 to 61 to 62 in assembly for AVR

Tags: assembly, avr

How to increase the address in SRAM, I want to store data with an erratic amount between 0 and 20 data.

Example:

```
1st data store in $ 60 address
2nd data store in address $ 61
.
.
.
.
.
```

Thanks

Comment: Use indirect addressing, `ST` instruction.

Answer (score 1):

The register file of AVR has three pointers, which can be used for inderect data access. They are **X** (which is a combination of registers **r27:r26**), **Y** (**r29:r28**) and **Z** (**r31:r30**).

Operator LD is used to load data from an adress, ST to store it.

```
LDI r27, 0x05 // load 0x0543 into X register
LDI r26, 0x43 
LD r16, X  // read RAM at address X into register r16
...
ST Y, r16 // store a value from r16 into RAM at address Y
```

All three registers can be used with *pre-decrement* or *post-increment*. Pre-decrement first decreases value of pointer registers by 1 and then access the data at that address. Post-increment, vice-versa, first access the data, then increases the address. Syntax is -X (or -Y / -Z) for pre-decrement and X+ (or Y+ / Z+) for post-increment:

```
LDI r27, 0x02  // Load 0x0200 into X pointer register
LDI r26, 0x00
LD r16, -X // decreases X register, now r27 contains 0x01 and r26 - 0xFF,
           // and then reads value of RAM at address 0x01FF into r16

LDI r31, 0x03  // Load 0x0345 into Z pointer register
LDI r30, 0x45 
ST Z+, r16 // stores value from r16 to address 0x0345, and increment r31:r30 by 1
           // now r31 contains 0x03 and r30 - 0x46
```

So, to store multiple data into consecutive addresses you can use multiple post-increment instructions:

```
LDI r27, 0x00 // Load 0x0060 into X
LDI r26, 0x60 
ST X+, r16 // store r16 to 0x0060
ST X+, r17 // store r17 to 0x0061
ST X+, r18 // store r18 to 0x0062
ST X+, r19 // store r19 to 0x0063
etc...
```